# Custom name of primaryKey in DS Model

Tags: ember.js

All tables in my database have unique primary key, which is created by connecting singular table name with "_id". For instance "phrase_id" in table "phrases" or "user_id" in table "users".

Ember requires to use "id" for primary key in json results. I have managed to overwritte this by setting custom ApplicationSerializer:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: 'phrase_id'
});
```

Anyway, that solution will set the new id key to all models, when I need custom key to every of them. How I can fix that? I suppose that I need to create some sort of anonymous function that will dynamically creating primaryKey depending on the model name, but how can I bind model name to that function?

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: function() {
        return modelName+'_id';
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you need a custom key? You are fighting the convention EmberJS expects, wouldn't it be easier to transform your DB to meet the convention?

Comment: There will be a lot of work to do with other application, which are using database right now. It is strange to me, that application this sort is not able to change such property.

Comment: Ah well that's the thing, ember, rails, EF(code first) etc are all database second applications, so unless you happen to be in line with the conventions (buy a lottery ticket if this was a lucky accident), it's going to be one long fight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easiest just to declare serializers for each model type.

```
App.UserSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: 'user_id'
});

App.PhraseSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: 'phrase_id'
});
```

It's a lot of boilerplate code, but it's pretty simple, and as Tony Hopkinson said, you don't really want to fight Ember.js too much.